# React native maps Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:checkDebugManifest'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle

The maps library works fine in a old project with react native where react-native version is `0.55.3` and react native maps is `0.23.0`

In a new project after setting up, Android that is, while building the app I keep getting the following error:

```
info JS server already running.
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew app:installAgroShopDebug)...

> Configure project :app
WARNING: API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variant.getAssemble(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

> Task :react-native-maps:checkDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-maps:checkDebugManifest'.
> Failed to create parent directory '/home/shockwav3/Downloads/mFarming/newRN/mFarming/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build/intermediates/check_manifest_result' when creating directory '/home/shockwav3/Downloads/mFarming/newRN/mFarming/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build/intermediates/check_manifest_result/debug/checkDebugManifest/out'
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar issue when I upgraded react-native. Strangely I fixed it by running metro with `sudo`

Comment: yeah I later figured that out, forgot to update. Any ideas why this is happening. Any commands now I try to run, project dependent ofcourse, needs `sudo` now and it wasn't needed before.